# How to create an SQL time-in-location table from location/timestamp SQL data stream

Tags: sql, timestamp, location, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I have a question that I'm struggling with in SQL.

I currently have a series of location and timestamp data. It consists of devices in locations at varying timestamps. The locations are repeated, so while they are lat/long coordinates there are several that repeat. The timestamp comes in irregular intervals (sometimes multiple times a second, sometimes nothing for 30 seconds). For example see the below representational data (I am sorting by device name in this example, but could order by anything if it would help):

```
Device     Location     Timestamp
X          A            1
X          A            1.7
X          A            2
X          A            3
X          B            4
X          B            5.2
X          B            6
X          A            7
X          A            8
Y          A            2
Y          A            4
Y          C            6
Y          C            7
```

I wish to create a table based on the above data that would show entry/exit or first/last time in each location, with the total duration of that instance. i.e:

```
Device     Location     EntryTime     ExitTime     Duration
X          A            1             3            2
X          B            4             6            2
X          A            7             8            1
Y          A            2             4            2
Y          C            6             7            1
```

From here I could process it further to work out a total time in location for a given day, for example.

This is something I could do in Python or some other language with something like a while loop, but I'm really not sure how to accomplish this in SQL.
It's probably worth noting that this is in Azure SQL and I'm creating this table via a Stream Analytics Query to an Event Hubs instance.
The reason I don't want to just simply total all in a location is because it is going to be streaming data and rolling through for a display for say, the last 24 hrs.

Any hints, tips or tricks on how I might accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I've looked and haven't be able to quite find what I'm looking for - I can see things like datediff for calculating duration between two timestamps, or max and min for finding the first and last dates, but none quite seem to tick the box. The challenge I have here is that the devices move around and come back to the same locations many times within the period. Taking the first occurrence/timestamp of device X at location A and subtracting it from the last, for example, doesn't take into account the other locations it may have traveled to in between those timestamps. Complicating things further, the timestamps are irregular, so I can't simply count the number of occurrences for each location and add them up either.

Maybe I'm missing something simple or obvious, but this has got me stumped! Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe grouping would work

```
SELECT Device, Location, [EntryTime] = MIN(Timestamp), [ExitTime] = Max(Timestamp), [Duration] = MAX(Timestamp)- MIN(Timestamp)
FROM <table>
GROUP BY Device, Location
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't that just give me the first and last instance of the location and calculate the total time inbetween? So if a device X was in location A from 10am-11am, B from 11am-12pm and back to A from 12pm-1pm, wouldn't that location just say it was in A from 10am-1pm (3hrs) when in fact it was only there for 2hrs?

Comment: Also, I tried the above and it's not super straight forward to groupby when it's a stream. It needs a window of time, which kind of negates the point of it being real time.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on similar issue, to some extent in my dataset.

```
SELECT U.*, TO_DATE(U.WEND,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI') - TO_DATE(U.WSTART,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI') AS DURATION
FROM  
(
SELECT EMPNAME,TLOC, TRUNC(TO_DATE(T.TDATETIME,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI')) AS WDATE, MIN(T.TDATETIME) AS WSTART, MAX(T.TDATETIME) AS WEND FROM EMPTRCK_RSMSM T 
GROUP BY EMPNAME,TLOC,TRUNC(TO_DATE(T.TDATETIME,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI'))
) U
```